# How to concatenate two Twig variables in a loop

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I'm trying to create dynamically variable name so the result to be as the one below

```
{{ form_label(form.user_1) }}
 {{ form_label(form.user_2) }}
 {{ form_label(form.user_3) }}
 {{ form_label(form.user_4) }}
```

Here's what I tried so far

```
{%  for user in users %}
      {{ form_label(form.user~'_'~loop.index) }}
 {% endfor %}
```

but get

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [you have to use the *attribute()* function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).

If this doesn't work with the concatenation in the *method* parameter, try to concatenate it first in a variable like this :

```
{% set userIndex = 'user_' ~ loop.index %}
```

And then you should try this :

```
{{ form_label(attribute(form, userIndex)) }}
```

Comment: When I do `{{ form_label(attribute(form, 'user_1') }}` it works but by using userIndex  I get the error described in my post.